# collect an array of hashes that matches a record ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes with various records in them. I have a value which I want to cross reference against that array and if it matches, pull out that record and use it.

```
>> concurrent_jobs.job_products
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<JobProduct id: 365, job_id: 91, product_id: 181, quantity: 3, frozen_cache: {}, created_at: "2014-08-13 15:54:21", updated_at: "2014-08-14 09:56:37">, #<JobProduct id: 366, job_id: 91, product_id: 363, quantity: 1, frozen_cache: {}, created_at: "2014-08-13 16:02:40", updated_at: "2014-08-13 16:02:40">]>
```

So let's say in the above array I want to collect the entire record that matches `product_id: 363` and then begin to use its other information such as quantity etc. How do I do it?

here is the method I have written so far

```
def product_quantity_in_current_unconfirmed_jobs(concurrent_jobs, original_product)
    concurrent_jobs.job_products.map do |x|
        b = x.product.id
        if b == original_product.id
            raise
        end

    end
end
```

I am sure there is a more eloquent way to do this. I'm just learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is an ActiveRecord association, you probably just want to query the association directly:

```
concurrent_jobs.job_products.where(product_id: 363).first
```

This will execute a SQL query to return just that one record (you can see that query by tailing your log/development.log), rather than returning all the records and forcing you to iterate them in your app.

That said, in the general case, if this were not ActiveRecord and you had an array of hashes, you could use [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (to grab all matching records) or [Enumerable#detect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect) (to grab the first matching record):

```
matching_records = array.select {|entry| entry[:product_id] == 363 }
```

or:

```
first_matching_record = array.detect {|entry| entry[:product_id] == 363 }
```